# Yii2 Separate sessions and cookies. Unable to verify your data submission

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to setup yii2 on shared hosting environment using apache. I'm using yii 2.0.3 and advanced template.
Application seems to work fine. What I can't get to work is to separate sessions and cookies as described in the documentation tutorial, https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-shared-hosting.md. In the last part there is some code to add to backend/config/main.php but when I add it I can't login to backend anymore getting following error:

> Bad Request (#400)
>   Unable to verify your data submission.

And here is the code I add to backend/config/main.php:

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_backendCSRF',
        'csrfCookie' => [
            'httpOnly' => true,
            'path' => '/admin',
        ],
    ],
    'user' => [
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_backendIdentity',
            'path' => '/admin',
            'httpOnly' => true,
        ],
    ],
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'BACKENDSESSID',
        'cookieParams' => [
            'path' => '/admin',
        ],
    ],
],
```

So how can I fix this to work properly? Let me know if you need additional info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also add the code of how you are `POST`-ing to the backend? Is it a form you did yourself? `ActiveForm`? 9 out of 10 times this error just means no `CSRF token` was found in the post data.

Comment: @Blizz It's the standard login form that yii2 advanced template has for the login in login.php file, https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/backend/views/site/login.php, also it has a hidden input element named _backendCSRF with a value.

Comment: Never mind this was just a (stupid) path mistake, because I was testing on localhost and the application is in a separate folder the path variable in main.php should contain path from root: `'path' => '/folder/admin'`.